# Crawling text from website with Python Requests and BeautifulSoup fails

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I would like to read some job ads automatically. For this, I implemented the procedure below which works quite well for most web pages:

```
def getTextFromWeb(url):
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
    temp = soup.findAll(text=True)
    xvec = []
    for x in temp:
        if (len(x) > 1):
            xvec.append(x)
    text = '\n'.join(xvec)
    return text
```

However, I'm not able to read in the relevant text for a web page with included javascript.
Any ideas how to enhance the procedure above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: reason for not getting all the text is that the page has iframe. requests library is not *browser* that knows how to fetch all the assets/content  the initial url will tell the browser to download / show ..

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is within the `<script>` tags in the source html. You need to parse from there which comes in json format:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import json

url = 'https://jobs.swp.de/jobs/4775408/Regionalleiter_(m_w_d)_Donaueschingen___Freudenst'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonData = json.loads(script.text)
print(jsonData['description'])
```

Comment: Appears it doesn't follow the same structure. You have to use url `https://jobs.swp.de/jobs/4799323/Medizinproduktberater___Pharmareferent_Wundversor?ModuleUrl=__F4WZF__%2FSagsProxy%2FGetJobOffer%2F4799323&resultId=`

Comment: And then your `getTextFromWeb()` function should work with that url